# Testing array length in jUnit5

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have this problem where I have to test if an array has a length of 3.

```
private Number[] number;
```

Here's my test to check if my array has a length of 3

```
@Test
void arrayHasALengthOf3(){
     Number[] number;

     assertTrue(number == 3);
}
```

I don't really know how I can solve this so can you guys help me out ...

Comment: number is not initalized, so it won't have length 3. You also would get the length using number.length(). I guess using an IDE and checking what it has to say about your code would be a good start to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions.

```
@Test
void arrayHasALengthOf3() {
   final int EXPECTED_LENGTH = 3;
   Number[] number = new Number[EXPECTED_LENGTH]; // you need to initialize it.

   // Use number.length to get the length of the array.
   assertEquals(number.length, EXPECTED_LENGTH);
}
```

You can either initialize the array with a class that contains `Number[]` in it.

Your main problem was how you **defined the array** & how you check for the **length**.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to make this kind of check?
If you initialize `Number[] number = Number[3]` array in the test there is no point to assert length as it will have always length of 3(unless you reassign the variable somewhere on the way which you shouldn't do most likely).
It would be different if you would like to check how many not null values are in the array or check if it contains expected values:

```
public class NumbersTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        Number[] numbers = new Number[]{1, 2, null};

        long count = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, count);
        Assertions.assertTrue(numbers.length == 3); //this will be always true unless you reassign numbers variable
        Assertions.assertArrayEquals(numbers, new Number[] {1, 2, null}); //check if contains expected values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

    @Test
    void arrayHasALengthOf3(){
        Number[] number = new Number[3];
        assertThat(number).hasSize(3);
    }
```